# I am trying to display the clicked numbers with the clicked operator sign and show the result when ehe equal button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My code seems to only works with just adding two numbers, after that it get messed up. It doesn't work when i keep adding multiple numbers. what am i doing wrong. My plan was to show all the numbers and operator sign on display and show the result when the equal button is clicked.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Calculator() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('')
  const [displayInput, setDisplayInput] = useState('')
  const [operator, setOperator] = useState('')
  const [currentNumber, setCurrentNumber] = useState('')
  const [previousNumber, setPreviousNumber] = useState('')

  function handleNumber(e){
    setCurrentNumber(currentNumber + e.target.value)
    setInput(currentNumber + e.target.value)
    setDisplayInput(input + e.target.value)
  }

  function handleOperator(e){
    console.log("-----Operator-----")
    if(currentNumber === '') return
    if(previousNumber !== ''){
      console.log("****checked******")
      handleCalculation()      
    }

    setOperator(e.target.value)
    setPreviousNumber(currentNumber)
    setInput(previousNumber + e.target.value)
    setDisplayInput(input + e.target.value)
    setInput('')
    setCurrentNumber('')
  }

  function handleCalculation(){
    if (operator === '+'){
      setDisplayInput(parseFloat(previousNumber) + parseFloat(currentNumber))
    }
    setCurrentNumber(parseFloat(previousNumber) + parseFloat(currentNumber))
    setOperator('')
    setPreviousNumber('')
    setInput('')
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>{displayInput}</p>
      </div>
      <button value = {1} onClick = {handleNumber}>1</button>
      <button value = {2} onClick = {handleNumber}>2</button>
      <button value = {3} onClick = {handleNumber}>3</button>
      <button value = {'='} onClick = {handleCalculation}>=</button>
      <button value = {'+'} onClick = {handleOperator}>+</button>
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default Calculator;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently resetting your displayInput everytime you do anything.

I suggest these fixes:
On your `handleNumber`:
`setDisplayInput(input + e.target.value)` has to become
`setDisplayInput(prevDisplay => prevDisplay + e.target.value)`

On your `handleOperator`:
`setDisplayInput(input + e.target.value)` becomes
`setDisplayInput(prevDisplay => prevDisplay + e.target.value)`.

This is because you are resetting your `input` state variable everytime you click on your operator so you can use the previousState of the `displayInput` variable to make the string as you wanted it to be.